# Does JFrog Artifactory Eventual Binary Provider clean up local artifact?

Tags: amazon-s3, artifactory

I have my JFrog Artifactory configured to use an Eventual Binary Provider in the cloud (AWS). I can't find any good documentation on how/if 'garbage collection' is done locally once the artifact is pushed to the cloud. I can see the local cache looks like it contains everything in the cloud storage, but will JFrog eventually clean this up?

Answer (score 1):

(I assume you are using the S3 bucket)
The [eventual provider](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=136876980) is the bridge between your AWS S3 bucket and Artifactory wherein the artifacts are deployed to the S3 bucket. The “eventual” directory contains 3 subdirectories: “_pre”, “_add”, “_delete”. Those folders are practically the queues of events that should be transmitted to the next provider, the cloud storage provider.

The files in the eventual should be deleted once the files are deployed to the S3 bucket. Can you elaborate on what exactly is happening? Are you talking about the cache sub-folder in the data folder or the actual eventual folder?

Comment: I was talking about the cache sub-folder. I'm sure it's probably working correctly because I've been pushing large images and the disk space available on the on-prem server where I am hosting Artifactory doesn't change, and I see stuff in S3. But what I see in S3 just looks like what is in the local cache.

Comment: You are correct. The cache folder (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Cached+Filesystem+Binary+Provider) will hold the downloaded artifacts with the LRU method as a cleanup method. The cache would definitely clear based on the LRU for new artifacts that are downloaded to be cached. Do refer to the wiki link attached for more understanding on the cache.